# Mysql foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am receiving an error when attempting to create some tables in mysql with the foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE session (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
date DATE,
room VARCHAR(30) NULL,
CONSTRAINT session_pk PRIMARY KEY (date),
CONSTRAINT session_fk FOREIGN KEY (code) 
    REFERENCES module(code));

CREATE TABLE module (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT module_pk PRIMARY KEY (code));
```

Here are the two tables I am trying to create, the syntax I've used matches w3 schools and both data types are the same so I cannot see how this is incorrect, any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: You are referencing a table which is yet to be created

Comment: Just define the `module` table first:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e298a.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks! I did ponder that at first and tried to create it but didn't get it wrote down correctly, this has worked! :)

Comment: Now it's not actually setting the foreign key for column code in the table course here is my code so far, can anyone see an issue: CREATE TABLE course (
code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT course_pk PRIMARY KEY (code));

CREATE TABLE module (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT module_pk PRIMARY KEY (code),
CONSTRAINT module_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_code) 
 REFERENCES course(code));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a foreign key on table before creating the referencing table.

Interchanging the order of query will work :

```
CREATE TABLE module (
`code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT module_pk PRIMARY KEY (`code`));

CREATE TABLE `session` (
`code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`date` DATE,
room VARCHAR(30) NULL,
CONSTRAINT session_pk PRIMARY KEY (`date`),
CONSTRAINT session_fk FOREIGN KEY (`code`) 
REFERENCES module(`code`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE module (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT module_pk PRIMARY KEY (code));

CREATE TABLE session (
code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
date DATE,
room VARCHAR(30) NULL,
CONSTRAINT session_pk PRIMARY KEY (date),
CONSTRAINT session_fk FOREIGN KEY (code) 
    REFERENCES module(code));
```